# How to Send and Receive a LIST via MSMQ / C#

Tags: c#, list, msmq, send

How can I send and receive a LIST object via MSMQ in C#?

Hard to find suggestions.

Detail examples greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just retrieve the data from the database and add them to a list

Comment: Consider to use WCF with MSMQ binding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send the list, you may just do:

```
queue.Send(list);
```

To receive the list, use this:

```
queue.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(new Type[]{typeof(List<T>)}); //Replace T with the type your list holds
Message message = queue.Receive();
List<T> list = (List<T>)message.Body;
```

When the message is sent, the object is formatted using XML. So, when receiving, you must specify that the queue uses a XML formatter with whatever type of list you have. Then, after receiving, the message's body must be casted to the list of the proper type.

Comment: I'm not using WCF...so this answer above was the best

Comment: @user3063679 Mark it as best answer so that this thread can be closed.

Comment: @user3063679 There should be a checkmark near the up and down arrows next to my answer. Click on that. For more info, visit https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.

Comment: @user3063679 Are you going to mark it as best answer? Stack Overflow guidelines say not to just leave a post after it is answered, and instead mark the best answer.

Comment: @user3063679 Read the link I sent you